# Centering Content in Flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, layout, components, center, alignment

I'm building a custom component that extends SkinnableContainer. I can center the content either vertically or horizontally inside it, but not both-- and that is what I need.

I'm setting the layout to HorizontalLayout for the component and setting verticalAlign to middle.

Then I'm creating a canvas to surround another component that goes inside this component, and setting that canvas width to 100%, and then setting textAlign=center, but no dice.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the horizontalCenter and verticalCenter properties to center your groups. The value is the number of pixels from either center where the sign of value denotes direction, 0 is absolute center.

This'll do the trick (assuming you want horizontal layout for your items). The 's' namespace refers to the spark components, since you're asking about flex 4 I assume Halo isn't of interest.

```
<s:Group>
    <!-- Any parent with BasicLayout will acknowledge horizontalCenter and verticalCenter -->
    <s:layout>
         <s:BasicLayout />
    </s:layout>

    <s:Group horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0">
        <s:layout>
            <s:HorizontalLayout/>
        </s:layout>

        <s:Button />
        <s:Button />
        <s:Button />
    </s:Group>
</s:Group>
```

Comment: No problem, happy to help! Nice site you've got btw, keep up the good work!

Comment: Thanks! Yours too... though I can't read anything the design is very pretty

Comment: The confusing part about that is both horizontalCenter and verticalCenter properties take an Object as a parameter, as opposed to a Number or int with zero explanation as to why in the documentation:  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/langref/spark/primitives/supportClasses/GraphicElement.html#horizontalCenter

Comment: Actually, it's an object because you can specify more complex layout behaviour than simply pixels back and forth, such as "col1:10", which would then be interpreted by the compiler as a string instead of a number. Parsing is left to the component. This is called constraintColumns, you can read more about it here: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=size_position_5.html (Flex 3, although I assume it still applies to at least the components in the mx namespace).